# Browsing directories in gvim not working with version 7.3

Tags: vim, directory

I recently moved from gvim 7.0 to 7.3, and notice that I am unable to use gvim to browse directories.

With gvim 7.0 (`VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Aug  4 2010 07:19:40)`), if I invoke gvim with `gvim .`, I get the following in the editor window:

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v125)
"   {{path hidden}}/stackoverflow/gvim_dir
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:exec
" ============================================================================
../
bar
foo
```

but with gvim 7.3 (`VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Nov 26 2012 08:32:39)`
), it is blank.

Since I thought some setting must be different between the two installations, I tried searching for it on the internet, and came across this article [Vim Recipes: Browsing Directories](http://vim.runpaint.org/other-uses-vim/browsing-directories/#note1). I tried with the `Ex` (as well as `ex`) command given there, but it didn't work.

From the directory listing seen in gvim 7.0 and from that article, I guess there's a `netrw` setting I need to change. I searched for that here on SO, but only found this post relevant [Opening a directory in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930636/opening-a-directory-in-vim). From the answers given there, I could not figure out how to enable it.

I also looked through the [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com), and came across useful tips which explain how to *use* the directory browsing, but could not find out how to *enable* it. Could you please help me identify the settings required to enable directory browsing in gvim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember recent fixes to this plugin. Please try the latest (beta) version from the author's web site: http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I shall try this in within a few days, and see how that works. I am quite sure it will work, since the answer has come from you. :)